# How do I change the name of a dotnet new template when creating new projects?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I've created a `dotnet` template for use with `dotnet new`. When creating new projects from this template, it works fine however the assembly and namespace name is still "Template", rather than the new project.

I've tried creating a new project and manually setting the name with the `--name` flag and `--output` flag, but to no avail.

I suspect there's a variable I can use somewhere, perhaps in the template.json file?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

You have to set template then use option params like **-n** param and give name.
For example,

```
dotnet new web -n myBestName
```

you can see more about cli
source [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x)

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `sourceName` in your `template.json` file.

You can refer to this page to find the purpose of each field.

```
"sourceName": {
  "description": "The name in the source tree to replace with the name the user specifies",
  "type": "string"
},
```

http://json.schemastore.org/template

A basic example of `template.json` file would look like this. Notice the `sourceName`

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
    "author": "Me",
    "classifications": [ "web api", "asp.net core", "C#" ],
    "identity": "WebApi.Template",
    "name": "WebApi.Template",
    "shortName": "WebApiTemplate",
    "tags": {
      "language": "C#",
      "type": "project"
    },
    "sourceName": "WebApi.Template",
    "preferNameDirectory" : true
  }
```

If you use `template.json` similar to above, you can give your component name in cli command either with `dotnet new YourTemplateName -n YourComponentName` or running just `dotnet new YourTemplateName` inside the folder named with your component  name.